# Apply legend label to fill and color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I am making a number of plots where for the same data series I produce, for example, a line plot and a ribbon plot. I then manually assign labels so that the legend looks nice. Is there a way to avoid typing out the labels multiple times like the below and simply do it once and have it apply to all the scales?

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mass, y=height, color=gender, fill=gender)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(labels=c("Female", "Male")) +
  scale_fill_brewer(labels=c("Female", "Male"))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Modify the data so the values of the `gender` column are Female and Male

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
starwars %>% filter(mass > 1000)
  mutate(gender = case_when(
    gender == "masculine" ~ "Male",
    gender == "feminine"  ~ "Female",
    TRUE ~ "Other")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=mass, y=height, color=gender, group = gender, fill=gender)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_log10() # Because Jabba is an absolute unit
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or create a named vector. Disadvantage to keep "other" as NA (although else, there is only NA in this case).

I have not scaled for Jabba.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mylabels <- c(feminine = "Female", masculine = "Male")
starwars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=mass, y=height, color=gender, fill=gender)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_brewer(labels=mylabels) +
  scale_fill_brewer(labels=mylabels)
#> Warning: Removed 29 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
#> Warning: Removed 29 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>